# Using WHERE IS NULL returns all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I have a query that joins three tables and returns an aliased calculation as a final field. Often that value is null when there's a null in a field that was joined on. The join works well.

I want to return just records where I'm getting Nulls in my calculated field.

But if I add

```
WHERE field_name IS NULL
```

to the end I get no records

If I add

```
WHERE field_name IS NOT NULL
```

I get the whole set which I can see several records as in fact null

Any explanation on why or how to fix this?

Edit: I found a solution for my case. The field name was an alias for a calculation above. When I duplicated the calculation in the where clause, instead of putting the alias, it ran correctly.

Comment: Are you sure they're actual `NULL`s as opposed to the string `'NULL'`? You may have to show more of the query.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for us to see the join and the expression you're calculating.

Comment: Oh. Just a thought - are you doing something in your `SELECT` clause along the lines of `a * b * field_value * c as field_value` - that is, creating an alias that matches an existing column name? Because if so, be aware that `WHERE` runs *before* `SELECT` does, and so it'll be filtering the *column*, not your computed value.

Comment: @Damien, I think you might be onto something with that last suggestion. It's not clear what OP meant by "where I'm getting Nulls in my field".

Comment: Post your entire query (or enough to reproduce the problem),  Something else is causing the unexpected results - `IS NOT NULL`  works just as you expect it to.

Comment: Note that in many RDBMS the empty string `''` is different to `NULL` - could the function be returning an empty string?

Comment: Research Anti-Semi joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my case. The field name was an alias for a calculation above. When I duplicated the calculation in the where clause, instead of putting the alias, it ran correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Given an outer join:

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table2.table1_id = table1.id
```

the way to apply a `is null` filter to the joined table is to put it in the join condition:

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table2.table1_id = table1.id
    and table2.col1 is null
```

and **NOT**:

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table2.table1_id = table1.id
where table2.col1 is null
```

Because if the join misses, all columns in the joined table are null, so using `is null` in the `where` will return all rows the joined to row that had a null *and* all rows that did not join.\